# Full Drop up menu OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am having a problem with trying to create drop up menu on click. 
First of all, there is the real site that I am working on. https://socialmanagement.000webhostapp.com/
under 736px width, the menu will turn to one button. The problem is that on mobile devices it's really buggy. If you click it on phone, it will automatically proceed you to the "href" of the last button in the menu even if it's not showing. Also, the menu won't go down after another clicking the "home" button

I need to drop up to a menu that I click on the button (the button will stay in the same position not like right now where it goes up) and it will stay until user clicks on it once again. 
Thank a lot for any advice

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar" id="myTopnav" >
    <div class="dropup">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <img src="images/Icons/home.png" />  </a>
        <div class="dropup-content" >
            <a href="#home" >   <img src="images/Icons/home.png" /> Home</a>
            <a href="#news">    <img src="images/Icons/about.png" /> News</a>
            <a href="#contact"> <img src="images/Icons/info.png" /> Contact</a>
            <a href="#home">    <img src="images/Icons/menu.png" /> Home</a>
            <a href="#news">    <img src="images/Icons/pic.png" /> Newssssssssssss</a>
            <a href="#contact"> <img src="images/Icons/about.png" /> Contact</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT (the First scrip that I got here was bad so I have to change it to this one, still can't close it from a mobile device):

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.icon')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery `toggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

First of all, in your provided HTML code, there is no `myDropdown` element. So, first we need to add that **id** to the `dropup-content` element. Then, we can just toggle a class of `show` when the `a` or in your case, the icon, is clicked. So, here it is:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar" id="myTopnav" >
     <div class="dropup">

                    <!-- You don't need javascript void here, we just won't include href.-->
                    <a class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <img src="images/Icons/home.png" />  </a>

          <!-- We add id="myDropdown" to the dropup-content element.-->
           <div class="dropup-content" id="myDropdown">
                        <a href="#home" >   <img src="images/Icons/home.png" /> Home</a>
                        <a href="#news">    <img src="images/Icons/about.png" /> News</a>
                        <a href="#contact"> <img src="images/Icons/info.png" /> Contact</a>
                        <a href="#home">    <img src="images/Icons/menu.png" /> Home</a>
                        <a href="#news">    <img src="images/Icons/pic.png" /> Newssssssssssss</a>
                        <a href="#contact"> <img src="images/Icons/about.png" /> Contact</a>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show")
}
// This is all you need to toggle on/off the menu,
// no need of that extra function with a for loop that you have in your code.
```

Of course, this goes without saying, you must edit the `show` class in your CSS in a way that you would like it to look.

As for the other question, how to stick the menu in a same position, you just add **`position: absolute`** to that element in your CSS, with the **`top/left/right/bottom`** coordinates that you like, and give it a `z-index: 2(or higher)` to make sure its on top of every other element. Hope this clears your issues.

Comment: I have chnaget script up there, thank you, but can you take a look right now what can I do to make it work on phone? To click and the dropup menu roll up and click once again to roll down. Also How can I make the "Menu button" to be "glued" and stay at it place. not to roll up with menu, Thank you

Comment: @MichaelFlorian I have edited my answer, it should do what you're looking for now, give it a look.

Comment: Glad I could help :) If you could, mark the answer above as accepted, if you found it helpful enough. Cheers :D

Comment: Done :D Thankx!